# I was able to review the same post twice, in two review queues

Tags: bug, review

I'm mostly reviewing stuff over at the gamedev SE. A late answer can also show up in the first posts section. If I review it in either of those two, it does not show up in the other one. If, however, I open each section in a separate tab, and the same answer shows up in both tabs, I can review it twice (no error whatsoever, it just works).

For example: [review #1](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/17284) and [review #2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/17285), both on  the same answer.

Is this a known issue? Or is it an issue at all? Since a normal review under a section makes the answer disappear from the other, I'm guessing this is kind of an exploit.

Comment: "I can review it twice" - did you try? Does that actually work, or does the second attempt result in an error?

Comment: It worked for me a few mins ago. Later edit: and again.

Comment: Thanks for confirming - the question wording was somewhat ambiguous about this particular point.

Comment: Sorry about that :) I'll edit the question.

Comment: Not sure it's a bug, but agree it should be blocked.

Comment: I remember this happening to me several months ago on [SO].

Comment: Revoking the bounty since this is a duplicate.